# Google spreadsheet: Insert empty row between non-duplicate row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet.

My problem is, in my google spreadsheet, when duplicate row is found, I cannot insert an empty row between them. But if different i.e. *non-duplicate* row found, I can insert an empty row between them.

Please help me.

Comment: How is this a JavaScript problem? What JavaScript are you using to insert rows?

Comment: @t0mm13b _really_ good job. :)

Comment: yes.. i  insert empty row using google spreadsheet function.

Comment: This has sat for a long time, but hasn't gotten any clearer by aging. One problem, the tags were wrong. Still... Can you clarify the question, please? If you provide some code that is giving you trouble, that would be most helpful.